# Regular expression to extract full content inside a div

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

How to extract the full html content inside a div ? I tried this code,

```
$html= '<html>
            <body>
                <div id="test">
                    <div id="mydiv1">Hello</div>
                    <div id="mydiv2">How are you</div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>';

$attr = "id";
$value = "test";

$tag_regex = '/<div[^>]*'.$attr.'="'.$value.'">(.*?)<\\/div>/si';
preg_match($tag_regex,$html,$matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

By running this code I get the result,

```
 <div id="test">
    <div id="mydiv1">Hello</div>
```

Expected result,

```
<div id="test">
   <div id="mydiv1">Hello</div>
   <div id="mydiv2">How are you</div>
</div>
```

In my code the regular expression execute till the first occurrence of `</div>` . How can I get the full code inside `<div id="test">` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$div = $dom->getElementById('test');

$result = $dom->saveHTML($div);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this thing by regex?

Comment: @FrayneKonok: yes, but you need to deal with: whitespaces, attributes order, attributes quotes *(single, double, no quote at all)*, html comments, javascript strings, comments and regex, with css strings and comments, and obviously with nested tags. Are you ready to write this pattern?